# How to limit number of child nodes in parent node in JetBrains MPS

Tags: dsl, mps

I have concept **PytanieWielokrotnegoWyboru** and I need it to contain min 1 and max 4 child **OdpowiedzWielokrotna**.

[image: Screenshot 1 :]
[image: Screenshot 2 :]

Answer (score 2):

Use constraints on your "question" concept to implement a "can be parent" function that rejects any new children after there are already four present.

A checking rule that underlines in red all overflow "answers" would be another option.